# pthread in c unexpected declaration speifiers or '...' before '('

Tags: c, pthreads

here is a snippet of a program I've been working on. Basically, I am getting the same error message twice as described by the title. This is my first time working with pthreads so if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *User_choices();
void *Switch_statement(void *);
void *Server_function(void *);

pthread_t SEND_TO_SERVER_THREAD;
pthread_t PIC_COMMUNICATION_THREAD;
pthread_t USER_INTERFACE_THREAD;

char buf[1024];

void main()
{ // 1
    snprintf(buf, 1024, "string");  
    while(1)
        { // 2
        pthread_create(&USER_INTERFACE_THREAD, NULL, User_choices, NULL);  
        } // 3
} // 4

void *User_choices()
{ // 5
    int userinput;
    printf("Type 0 to reset sensor, 1 to ping, 2 to receive ADC value, 3 to quit the program: ");
    scanf("%i", &userinput);
    pthread_create(&PIC_COMMUNICATION_THREAD, NULL, Switch_statement, &userinput);
} // 6

void *Switch_statement((void *)userchoice))
{ // 7
    int user = (int)*userchoice;
    switch(user) 
    { // 8
        case 1:         
                printf("OTHER FUNCTIONS USUALLY GO HERE \n");
                break;
        case 2:                                     //RETRIEVE ADC CASE

                pthread_create(&SEND_TO_SERVER_THREAD, NULL, Server_function, (void *)&buffer); 
                break;
        case 3:
                exit(0);    
        case 0:                                     //RESET CASE
                printf("ONCE AGAIN, OTHER FUNCTIONS USUALLY GO HERE");
                break;                          //EXIT THE PROGRAM
        default:
                printf("Your entry is not a valid option! Try again \n");                               
    } // 9
} // 10

void *Server_function((void *)server_buffer))
{ // 11
    const char* send_to_server = (char)*server_buffer;
    HTTP_GET(send_to_server);
} // 12
```

Here are the error codes:

```
justpthread.c:31:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 void *Switch_statement((void *)userchoice))
                        ^
justpthread.c:53:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 void *Server_function((void *)server_buffer))
```

If I change just void main to int main, I get the same two error codes. If i take out the parentheses surround (void *), no matter when it's int main or void main, i get the following:

```
justpthread.c: In function ‘Switch_statement’:
justpthread.c:33:18: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
  int user = (int)*userchoice;
                  ^
justpthread.c:33:2: error: invalid use of void expression
  int user = (int)*userchoice;
  ^
justpthread.c:41:76: error: ‘buffer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     pthread_create(&SEND_TO_SERVER_THREAD, NULL, Server_function, (void *)&buffer); 
                                                                            ^
justpthread.c:41:76: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
justpthread.c:44:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
     exit(0); 
     ^
justpthread.c: In function ‘Server_function’:
justpthread.c:55:37: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
  const char* send_to_server = (char)*server_buffer;
                                     ^
justpthread.c:55:2: error: invalid use of void expression
  const char* send_to_server = (char)*server_buffer;
  ^
```

And you guys have me incredibly confused as far as the brackets go, so I numbered all of them. I'm seeing an even number, and they look like they alter directions properly.

Going off of additional recommendations, I changed my code like so:

```
void main()
{
    snprintf(buf, 1024, "string");  
    while(1)
        {
        pthread_create(&USER_INTERFACE_THREAD, NULL, User_choices, NULL);  
        }
}

void *User_choices()
{
    int userinput;
    printf("Type 0 to reset sensor, 1 to ping, 2 to receive ADC value, 3 to quit the program: ");
    scanf("%i", &userinput);
    pthread_create(&PIC_COMMUNICATION_THREAD, NULL, Switch_statement, &userinput);
}

void *Switch_statement(void *userchoice)
{
    int user = *((int*)userchoice);
    switch(user) 
    {
        case 1:         
                printf("OTHER FUNCTIONS USUALLY GO HERE \n");
                break;
        case 2:                                     //RETRIEVE ADC CASE

                pthread_create(&SEND_TO_SERVER_THREAD, NULL, Server_function, (void *)&buf);    
                break;
        case 0:                                     //RESET CASE
                printf("ONCE AGAIN, OTHER FUNCTIONS USUALLY GO HERE");
                break;                          //EXIT THE PROGRAM
        default:
                printf("Your entry is not a valid option! Try again \n");                               
    }
}
```

I changed int user... to

```
int user = *((int*)userchoice);
```

as recommended, and so I got the following error messages:

```
justpthread.c: In function ‘Server_function’:
justpthread.c:53:37: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
  const char* send_to_server = (char)*server_buffer;
                                     ^
justpthread.c:53:2: error: invalid use of void expression
  const char* send_to_server = (char)*server_buffer;
```

So it looks like it got rid of some of the previous errors. So I noticed now that server_buffer is having issues as well so I tried to change that to:

```
void *Server_function(void *server_buffer)
{
    const char* send_to_server = *((char*)server_buffer);
    //HTTP_GET(send_to_server);
}
```

And now I just have one error:

```
justpthread.c: In function ‘Server_function’:
justpthread.c:53:31: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  const char* send_to_server = *((char*)server_buffer);
```

Comment: Count your brackets and learn how to specify arguments in a function call.

Comment: `void main()` is illegal, use `int main()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last warning, you want to cast `void*` to `char*`, but with `*((char*)server_buffer` you are dereferencing pointer to `server_buffer` and casting `void*` to `char` and not to `char*`.

The proper way is:

```
const char* send_to_server = (char*)server_buffer;
```

Comment: that got rid of all of the issues, thank you everyone for pointing at the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the (parenthesis) around void * on those lines.

Comment: Note that the brackets are unbalanced as well:(

Comment: @cwshmidt, and Martin, I tried the recommend changes and get different, or at least the same errors. And i numbered the brackets, can someone explain to me how they aren't set up right?

Answer (score 0):

Try `void *userchoice` and

```
int user = *((int*)userchoice);
```

You cannot do anything with `void *` before you cast it.

Comment: I did what you said and it did not knock down a number of the issues. I tried to do the same thing with the other variable that had a similar issue, but I still have one error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance, and sorry I'm not too knowledgeable in this field.